# How to update title of posts?

Tags: wordpress, tags

I am using phpmyadmin

In every title of post contains "In x" (x is a number in the range 1 to 1000)

Example:

```
 In 434 Hello everybody ----> remove "In 434" -----> Hello everybody
 In 62 Hi everybody     ----> remove "In 62" ------> Hi everybody
 In 2 I am newmember    ----> remove "in 2"  ------> I am newmember
```

How to remove "In x" with sql queries ?

This is my code

```
SELECT wp_posts.post_title FROM wp_posts Where wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'
$result = preg_replace('/In \d+ /','',$title);
UPDATE wp_post SET post_content = $result
```

But is says an error

> "#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '$result = preg_replace('/In \d+ /','',$title)' at line 2"

Thank you very much ! Sorry for my bad English !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are attempting to execute PHP code (the `preg_replace()` line) on the MySQL server. This will not work, and MySQL's query language is not powerful enough to perform arbitrary pattern replacements such as this. You would instead need to write PHP code which will run the SELECT query, and then for each row returned apply the `preg_replace()` function to the 'title' field and run the UPDATE query to apply the change in the database.

There are many, many examples of how to write PHP code which interacts with a MySQL database, but why not use the Wordpress API and save yourself a lot of work? [`get_posts()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) and [`wp_update_post()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_update_post) are a good place to start; [the Wordpress function reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference#Post.2C_Custom_Post_Type.2C_Page.2C_Attachment_and_Bookmarks_Functions) in general will probably also be of use to you, especially the "Getting Started" section.